# DB query to get the stock status in magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

Get the product stock status in Magento 2.4.4 using the DB query

Comment: you can get stock details from single table "cataloginventory_stock_item" . Not need to join relation.

Answer (score 1):

You need **cataloginventory_stock_item** and **cataloginventory_stock_status** table.

> SELECT stock_item.product_id,stock_item.website_id,
> stock_item.qty,stock_status FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` as
> stock_item left join cataloginventory_stock_status as stock_status On
> stock_item.product_id = stock_status.product_id;